# overwrite zip file using php

Tags: php, zip

I wrote a method to create a zip entry and rewrite it if this function is called second time but it is not working. here is my code:

```
public function zipFile($filepath,$fileName){ 
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    $zip_name = $fileName.'.zip';       

    echo "$zip_name";          

         if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)===TRUE) {

     $zip->addFile($filepath,$fileName.'.csv');
     $zip->close();
     echo 'ok';
          } else {
     echo 'failed';
                   }       
          return '/home/daily_reports/'.$zip_name;

                          }
```

what is missing in my logic. I want to replace the file with new one if the method is called again

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not working as a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try explicitly deleting the zip file first if it exists. The overwrite option may not behave as expected.

```
clearstatcache();//For good measure clear out any cached file paths

$file = "{$filepath}/{$fileName}"
if(file_exists($file)){
    unlink($file);
}
```

However, I have had mysterious issues trying to use the built-in zip functionality in php, especially with platform differences, performance, and memory issues. I prefer to zip the files on the command line through php.

On linux/osx:

```
$cmd = "zip archivefile file1 file2";
exec($cmd);
```

On windows use 7zip, also from the command line. http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

```
$cmd = "7za.exe a archivefile.7z file1 file2";
exec($cmd);
```

Technically you don't need to install 7zip, you just need the stand alone exe, but you might need to install it first to get the exe. http://www.7-zip.org/download.html